# prevent 'delete[]' from source object's destructor from releasing our 'just stolen data'

Tags: c++

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/462608

```
string(string&& that)   // string&& is an rvalue reference to a string
{
    data = that.data;
    that.data = nullptr;
}
```

> What have we done here? Instead of deeply copying the heap data, we have just copied the pointer and then set the original pointer to null (***to prevent 'delete[]' from source object's destructor from releasing our 'just stolen data'***). In effect, we have "stolen" the data that originally belonged to the source string.

Please explain the line in bold from the above quote.

`that` is a rvalue so how would it be deleted from source object's destructor? Please give examples.

Comment: Without `that.data = nullptr`, when `that` destructed, it would release `that.data` aka `this->data` because of `data = that.data;`. "Source" in the link means `that`.

Comment: @LouisGo Request: Write an answer.

Comment: This function is missing the first line - it should `delete [] this->data;` otherwise previously allocated array will leak.

Comment: @user7860670 Please write an answer.

Comment: @user7860670 This seems to be a constructor, which means there's no previously allocated array.

Comment: It's a move constructor, so `that` is the "source object", `*this` is the destination.

Comment: The term "just stolen data" refers to the fact that `*this` (the object being constructed) has silently taken ownership of `that.data`  (the data owned and managed by the object `that`). The assignment `data = that.data;` causes the object being constructed (`*this`) and the object being moved from (`that`) to have the same value of `data`.    Hence two objects now contain the same pointer. If those objects are both destroyed, that `data` will be released twice by the destructor - giving undefined behaviour.    The assignment `that.data = nullptr` causes `that` to no longer own the data.

Comment: Why not just `std::swap(data, that.data);` and let `that`'s destructor take care of `that.data` which it had just acquired via swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the snippet before the quote. You may know `string` would `delete[] data` when it destructs.

```
~string()
{
    delete[] data;
}
```

Without `that.data = nullptr`, when `that` destructed, it would release `that.data` aka `this->data` because of `data = that.data;`.

"Source" in the link means `that`.

Answer (score 2):

The wording might be a little misleading.

The "source" mentioned is the "source object", i.e. the object that is referred to by `that`.

It might be easier to understand if you see something like

```
// Need std::move to turn source_object into an rvalue reference
string destination_object(std::move(source_object));
```